# GSON - Deserialize null values into "null " strings

Tags: java, string, null, gson, deserialization

I am facing with a IMHO a strange behaviour of GSON. Let's take the following example:

```
{
    "Name": "emaborsa",
    "Surname": null
}
```

and my POJO is:

```
public class User {

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Surname")
    private String surname;

    // getter and setter
}
```

I deserialize it using the following code:

```
Gson g = new Gson();
User user = g.fromJson(json, User.class);
```

The variable `name` is set with "emaborsa", the variable `surname` I expected it were set to null but there is a string "null " instead.
Is it the correct behaviour or am I missing something? I tried to google it but it is hard to find something related to `String` and `null`...

Comment: I don't see that issue. Are you sure that your json doesn't have "null" quoted? I copied your code for User and your code for deserializing. But I used a string variable for my json. Where are you getting your json from? A file? A variable?

Comment: Yes you are right, it was my fault. I missed a line in the code where the variables are concatenated like `user.getSurname() + " "` so I found the string `null `

Answer (score 0):

This worked fine for me, using your code as the basis:

```
package gsonexample3;

import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.annotations.*;

public class User {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Gson g = new Gson();
        User user = g.fromJson(json, User.class);
    }

    @SerializedName("Name")
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("Surname")
    private String surname;

    private static String json = "{\"Name\": \"emaborsa\", \"Surname\": null}";


}
```

Answer (score -1):

Looks like you have to specify that you want to serialize nulls.

`Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
        .setPrettyPrinting()
        .serializeNulls()`

Coming from - https://howtodoinjava.com/gson/serialize-null-values/